# На сколько жива концепция модульного програмирования, и что можно сделать с помощью ООП?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Я только начинаю делать маленькие вещи на JS, и сделал простой календарь, и нужны ответы от людей, опытных в веб. разработке на несколько вопросов!
[календарь](https://codepen.io/dontspeakjs/pen/LYGbJOG)

Я прекрасно понимаю, что читать  полностью и вникать в весь код никто не будет (пустая трата времени), НО прошу ваших ответов на более концептуальные вопросы:

1. **При данном функционале календаря (думаю он прост) как можно реализовать ООП?** Понятия не имею досих пор что есть ООП в JS? На 99.9999% ресурсов создаётся объект `person` и  с помощью класса `Person`, поэтому мне не очень понятно как применять ОПП в JS для создания проектов, которые не несут в себе обращение с пользовательскими данными, быть может вы просто подадите идею в стиле "сделать календарь объектом, у которого свойства это стили, а методы это создание различных блоков, и применение к ним стилей" ?!
2. Модульный подход . . . Если не вдумываться в `JS` код, то вы заметите, что данный календарь сделан на чистом `JS`, из `HTML` там только контейнер, в который мы просто вставляем календарь (можно прописать `document.body. . .` при создании модуля, и тогда html вообще не понадобится), и он либо принимает размеры контейнера, либо мы сами в объекте `config` задаём параметры календаря, так вот, **насколько эта практика используется в реальных проектах?** Ну например, я сейчас делаю todo лист и у меня загвоздка, поэтому я сделал этот календарь, чтобы в будущем его просто вставить модулем в этот todo . + Есть в том-же календаре элементы, типо 41го див блока в которых отображаются числа месяца, которые на мой взгляд бы было глупо прописывать в `html`, поэтому проще сделать это циклом (ну на мой субьективный взгляд)
3. **В чем профит использования ООП перед модульно - процедурном подходом**, т.к. по сути мой модуль это тоже приватная единица, которой не нужны внешние данные, и она не изменяет их, все переменные будут локальными в модуле, вставил в свой проект, настроил (настройки в проекте сделаны пока чисто формально, можно сделать хоть толщину и стиль рамки этого календаря офк) и забыл? **И не много ли у меня кода для простого календаря?**
4. **Как можно найти проекты людей (не большие типо слайдеров, калькулейторов, календариков, тудушек), код которых действительно написан грамотно?** (я к тому, что не просто нарваться на популистскую статью типо "как сделать крутой слайдер в js, или делаем суууперпростой калькулятор для новичков") Дело в том, что И Я  могу запостить на хабре свой календарь, НО его во первых засмеют, а во вторых недайбог найдутся те, кто возьмёт что-то для себя из него на заметку, **быть может на гитхабе (пока ещё ниразу не пользовался этим сайтом) есть подобное, из раздела НЕ мусор для новичков, с примерами правильного ООП, мудульного програмирования?**

Comment: Только-только начал понимать ООП пару месяцев назад (поэтому не решусь написать ответ), когда объем кода начал превышать 2000-3000 строчек, и появилась проблема управления кодом. Очень помогла книга `Стив Макконнелл - Совершенный код`.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME хм, я просто кроме js пока ничего не изучал, боюсь если честно читать книги общего назначения, там же наверное примеры из всяких c++ c# java . . . несмотря на то, что изучая один язык вы волей не волей начинаете понимать общие концепции других языков, всё равно сложные примеры без изучения языка вы не поймёте!

Comment: К сожалению, ответы будут основаны на мнениях, поэтому вам никто не сможет дать единственно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Боюсь, вы не найдете каноничных примеров ООП в приложениях написанных на javascript.

Javascript не самый удачный выбор для изучения ООП, т.к. классы в этом языке всего лишь синтаксический сахар над функцией-конструктором и prototype объектом.

Надо понимать, что под каждым языком программирования лежит определенная философия, понимание того для решения каких задач данный язык был создан и нацелен. Изначальная цель создания JS - написание небольших скриптиков на пару десятков строк, внедренных в HTML страничку. И это всё на что был, так сказать, замах.

Отсюда проистекает динамичность `this`, слабая типизирование, наличие глобальных переменных, `hoisting`, `coercion` и проч. и проч. Но волею судеб данный язык на хипстерской волне превратился в универсальный инструмент для написания всего спектра прикладных программ. То есть, изначально была придумана и создана "пилка для ногтей", а превратилась она в нечто на чем запустили конвейер по выпуску автомобилей.

На конвейере работают бригады рабочих, а программы пишут на галерах джуны, мидлы и сеньоры. Изначально интерпрайз-галеры гребли с помощью вёсел типа `Java`, `C++` и `C#`. Данные весла повлияли на культуру и технологию создания конечного продукта, которая во многом базируется на применении ООП.

И тут в интерпрайз ворвался нечесаный, со стаканчком из старбакса весь такой модный JS...
И "пилку для ногтей" стали переделывать, точнее обвешивать необходимым, чтоб этим можно было хоть как-то коллективно и по команде продакт-менеджера грести.

Такая вот информация к размышлению.

Answer (score 4):

Вопросов много, а в JS я не эксперт, поэтому отвечу что знаю.

### 3. ООП vs Модульность

ООП и модульность действительно имеют сходство, но можно сказать, что ООП – это развитие модульности. В ООП есть 4 базовых принципа:

1. Абстракция
2. Инкапсуляция
3. Наследование
4. Полиморфизм

А модульность это только инкапсуляция и возможно в какой-то мере абстракция. Без наследования и полиморфизма, а профит в них есть – повышение адаптивности кода и его переиспользования.

Однако здесь стоит смотреть на код в разном масштабе. Когда вы используете какие-то структуры данных и алгоритмы, или взаимодействие по сети с кучей настроек, или моделируете физический мир с визуализацией, то здесь пригодится объектно-ориентированное программирование во всей красе. Но на масштабе выше, особенно по части GUI (например, JavaBeans) и особенно в вебе, популярна разновидность ООП – [компонентно-ориентированное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (**КОП**).

### 2. Модульность в JS

Есть популярные фреймворки для фронтэнда – Angular, React, Vue. Насколько я знаю, они все придерживаются КОП, и делают это очень хорошо. Вы можете создать какой-нибудь компонент, в котором будет сразу HTML, CSS, JS (например, форму ввода пользовательской инфы), поместить внутрь него чей-то чужой компонент (например, красивое поле ввода email), и свой компонент положить ещё в чей-то чужой компонент (на страницах регистрации и редактирования юзверя). При этом, компоненты могут передавать друг другу какие-то значения и настройки, а их комбинация и настройка происходит гораздо проще и следовательно быстрее (на радость дизайнерам), чем традиционная модульность, где вручную создаваётся большая каша из HTML, CSS, JS и настроек всех элементов страницы.

Кстати, средние и крупные компании зачастую регламентируют используемые фронтэнд технологии (т.е, выбирают один из упомянутых фреймворков) и создают внутренние реестры компонентов, чтобы разработчики не тратили время на создание велосипедов, а [дизайнеры общались с разрабами на одном языке](https://habr.com/ru/post/507236/).

Так выглядит современная модульность, точнее ООП, а ещё точнее КОП, в клиентском JS. Но учтите, что это на масштабе дизайна и UI, если же вам нужны какие-то сложные алгоритмы, то вполне может пригодиться традиционное ООП (к слову, в основе JS лежит его разновидность – [прототипное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

### 4. Примеры

Примеры ищите в первую очередь на GutHub, а также можно смотреть по ключевым словам в [реестре пакетов JS – NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react). Но здесь знатоки современного JS подскажут лучше.

Из книг присоединяюсь к рекомендации про "Совершенный Код" Стива Макконелла, а также советую найти хороший современный учебник по одному из упомянутых фреймворков, если интересует развитие в направлении фронтэнд разработки.